# I need clarification for the following code in python and what :^38

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tree, xor

I need clarification for the following code in python and what `:^38`

```
for leaf in [*range(10)]+[2]:
  print(f'{"x"*(leaf*2+1):^38}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you want to use backticks ``` to make your snippet readable

```
for leaf in [*range(10)]+[2]: 
    print(f'{"x" + str(leaf*2+1):^38}')
```

Then first to the issue in the code. Your code iterates over the concatenation of two lists. The first one has a range object from 0->9 and the second one has the number two. I used the star to turn the range into it's elements, so you have a list from 0->9 and the number 2.

The part in the squiggly brackets before the colon is the expression to print. Since (leaf*2 + 1) is a number and "x" is not a function (I'd assume) you need to turn it into a string by using str()

The part after the colon c gives the string in the curly braces a space of 38 and aligns it in the middle of it. [Alignment in PEP-3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#standard-format-specifiers)

Comment: Since you edited the multiplication in, it's `print(f'{"x"*(leaf*2+1):^38}')` which results in a nice christmas tree

Answer (score 0):

first line:

```
for leaf in [*range(10)]+[2]:
```

you create list of [0,1,2...,10,2]

seconed line

```
  print(f'{"x"*(leaf*2+1):^38}')
```

you print x (leaf*2+1) times, with spaces beside it that make the all printed string in length of 38